# How to import NLTK in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, nltk, jython

I am a beginner in NetBeans environment and I want to use Jython so when I try to import NLTK I get this error what I should do to solve it ?

```
  Traceback (innermost last):
File"C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NewPythonProject2\src\newpythonproject2.py", line 10, in ?
ImportError: no module named nltk
```

Comment: `netbeans` supports `java` but `nltk` is a `python` library. There's no explicit support for `jython` in `nltk`.

Comment: netbeans supports python too but I can't  import nltk because of the problem above